How to make NFT with Solana?
I am the designer of a molten salt type solar power plant. I decided to convert my design to NFD and build a metaverse in space in an area analyzed in reality.I don't know how toconvertmy3DMAXfiles(.fbx) to NFD?And I don't know where to start?

You have 3 options:
Using the Metaplex Token Metadata Program - Nft Standard
https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata
Using the Metaplex Core - Next Solana NFT standard.
https://developers.metaplex.com/core
Using the Token Extensions - Decentralized way (using the metadata pointer)
https://spl.solana.com/token-2022
